# how to output custom image field (uri) from a Group entity on page.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, theming, commerce, entities

I have a custom image field associated with a "group" entity(Created by the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) Module) that is called field_header_image. Im looking to output the image uri as background style in the page.tpl.php template. To achieve a "Full Screen" effect, I need to get to the outside of the div containers which puts me into page.tpl.php. I simply need to print the url or uri for the image called field_header_image.

I used to use something like this but since Groups are not nodes, Im wondering how to access these fields?? the code below was in my old theme template using Organic Groups so the header image was a field in a node. easy to access!

```
<?php print file_create_url($node->field_header_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']); ?>
```

But that code throws an error now. Id like to be able to insert a similar php statement into my page.tpl.php template that references the entity_type of 'group' instead of 'node'.
From the devel module output in Krumo, I can see that the object is located here:

```
$...['content']['system_main']['group'][1]['field_header_image'][0]['#item']['uri']
```

I wish I could figure out how to turn that into a php statement but the problem with that output from Krumo is I need it to work for any group page and pull that pages content, it looks like this location would pull that specific groups header image(group 1)

Comment: install devel module. then before this line try to `dsm($node->field_header_image);` to see is there any data in field

Comment: the page array shows this: not sure how to format it correctly: 
    $...['content']['system_main']['group'][1]['field_header_image']['#object']->field_header_image['und'][0]['uri']

Comment: instead of using the uri, you could use [image url formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter)

Comment: Id like to get something like this in my preprocess page:
    $field = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_myfield', $node->field_myfield[$node->language][0], 'full');
    $markup = render($field);

Comment: did you try what I told you ?  var_dump($node->field_header_image)?

Comment: yes that doesnt show anything except an undefined variable error because the data is not a node, its is an entity created by the group module with a custom image field on the group type. Groups are entities in the new "Group" module. I had this working before when I used Organic Groups Module because those were nodes. Being a designer background, its a little trickier for me to navigate adding variables to the template.php when they become deeply nested which is I guess what happens when you add fields to entities? All I want is to access a fields data, seems like something so simple, lol.